# WebAuthenticationDetails getRemoteAddress() not returning real ip address of client

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using WebAuthenticationDetails in my application.The method of WebAuthenticationDetails's getRemoteAddress() returns same IP address even if i login in application from different client machine.This may be due to proxy server.Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is working behind a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) (for example nginx, Apache, etc.) then you'll always see IP of the reverse proxy machine in the WebAuthenticationDetails object. To solve this problem you can configure your reverse proxy in such a way that it will send client's IP address to your application server using a HTTP header. Then in your webapp get clinet's IP from this header.

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: Yes: 1) turn off your reverse proxy or 2) try to configure Spring Security in such a way that this header will be used during initialization of WebAuthenticationDetails (so you'll continue to use this object). Why exactly do you want another options?

Comment: i don't know how to configure spring security in web.xml

Comment: can you provide me any link which will help me to configure web.xml?

Comment: It is very simple to do. Check [corresponding entry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-web-xml) from the official documentation.

Comment: you said "2) try to configure Spring Security in such a way that this header will be used during initialization of WebAuthenticationDetails".but when does this happens??

Comment: See `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setDetails(...)` method and the constructor of WebAuthenticationDetails class.